# Meaning of mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x1031b

Tags: c#, windbg, strongname

Does anybody know what the meaning of **mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x1031b** is in the snippet of !eestack from WinDBG below?

```
0632e620 74c9e900 mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x103e4, calling mscorwks!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x7f70
0632e694 74c9e855 mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x10339, calling mscorwks+0x31c0
0632e6a0 74215058 (MethodDesc 0x7402b7c4 +0x18 System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert()), calling (MethodDesc 0x740c84fc +0 System.Security.SecurityRuntime.RevertAssert(System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef))
0632e6ac 73df4598 (MethodDesc 0x738bc65c +0xa0 System.Diagnostics.SharedUtils.CreateSafeWin32Exception(Int32)), calling (MethodDesc       0x7402b7c4 +0 System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert())
0632e6e4 73ee6fa0 (MethodDesc 0x738e064c System.Diagnostics.EventLog.get_OldestEntryNumber()), calling mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x1031b
0632e6f4 73df24ed (MethodDesc 0x738e06e8 +0x1bd System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CompletionCallback(System.Object)), calling (MethodDesc    0x738e064c +0 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.get_OldestEntryNumber())
0632e728 74bb8cef mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x5687, calling mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x5613
0632e73c 73df0fe4 (MethodDesc 0x738e096c +0x94 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.StaticCompletionCallback(System.Object, Boolean)), calling 739443d4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.UnauthorizedAccessException in mscorwks.dll causing app pool crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640210/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-mscorwks-dll-causing-app-pool-crashes)

Comment: Check the accepted answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640210/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-mscorwks-dll-causing-app-pool-crashes) on how to find out what caused the exception - it is thrown by the CLR, by examining the thread/call stack you can get some good hints on what lead to it.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, the offset (0x103e4) is way to large make the symbol name reliable.  Do make sure you got a good .pdb file from the Microsoft symbol server.  If this is the actual crash location then it is bombing on walking the stack.  There are some odds as well that you are looking at the wrong thread with the actual crash located in the garbage collector code.  We already know that CompletionCallback() catches all exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StackOverFlow posting from similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640210/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-mscorwks-dll-causing-app-pool-crashes)
Look at this posting in the Answers section sounds like same issue this individual had.
Sounds like .net - System.UnauthorizedAccessException in mscorwks.dll

Comment: OK This does seem quiet helpful, the asker of that question does not have an answer to how he fixed it though.

Comment: are you having reference errors within the using .. or GAC reference for this.. also is the error happening locally or on a remote server..? sounds like some security / permission issues possibly.. also did you type in the command that the answer gave you when attaching the mscor... via the debugger..??

Comment: The issue is happening locally, and yep I typed in the .loadby sos mscorwks command into WinDBG and I have had a look at !clrstack and !printexception. The code that is being called in the run up to the error is from Microsofts EventLog.cs class, it is calling a GetOldestEventLogRecord method from the advapi32.dll

Comment: When you are running this.. are you running it as Admin..?  Strong Names in general are for code security and publisher verification. If you're getting a strong name error, perhaps the file is corrupted or was replaced by a copy with a different signature.

Comment: The application is running as a service under the Local System account, also it can run for days/ weeks without a problem and then this will suddenly happen. Does it look like a problem with this advapi32.dll to you?

Comment: also do you have a code snippet that you may be able to post.. I wonder how are you Marshalling the code

Comment: The only line of code thats relevant in my application is eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(EventLogMonitor); It seems that the code causing the error is part of .NET monitoring the event log for entry written events

Comment: is this Managed Code or UnManaged Code..? also do you have access to the .dll source..? if not also check out this link if you have access to the code base http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/9622ca01-05c5-49bb-ab76-1adfb4c36a37  I also wonder if the EventLog needs to be Flushed / Cleared after a certain amount of time.. sounds like a issues with the log being too full and not having enough space but I could be wrong.. especially if you say it runs for a while and then crashes.. ..I can't tell without being in your position

Comment: but the error in general seems to relate to Security / Permissions.. wonder if there is a Sync issue with permissions and passwords / service accounts credentials sync ... what does the sys admin on your end have to say about these odd findings..??

Comment: The advapi32.dll is unmanaged but everything else is managed. Thats a good point about the event log being full, I will have a look into that

Comment: Perhaps you could implement a Flushing / Clear / Cleanup routine after the log reaches a certain point .. or they can perhaps allow the file to grow.. but if they don't have the resources to allow for that.. that's just like trying to overflow your 4oz coffee cup with 32oz of fluid.. it's a not a win win situation...

Comment: I think I am the sys admin unfortunately, I have set this application up to run as a service under the Local System account which should have full permissions,and if it didnt have enough permissions I guessed it wouldnt work at all, but working for a while and then crashing is weird if its a permissions issue

Comment: can you double check the full permissions as well.. I have seen stranger things.. also if you are Invoking unmanaged code.. make sure that you are disposing of the .dll properly .. it's once again hard to tell what's going on under the hood without seening some sort of code base..